# How to determine whether an image was taken from the library or from the camera

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, if-statement

I want to check via an if statement if an image is picked from the camera roll or is taken by the built in camera. How can I do this via an if-statement?
Thanks for your help!

**Code:**

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum) {

    toolbar.hidden = NO;
}

else{

    toolbar.hidden = YES;
}

imgView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Are you using `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: Yes I'm using UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply check the `sourceType`:

```
if (picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
    //image taken with camera
}
else{
    //image taken from camera roll
}
```

Do this in your `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method.

Comment: Being pedantic, you should check for `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary`, `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` and `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum`, although I admit this is not that Real World any more...

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answers. If an image is chosen (from camera or the library) i'll show a toolbar. How can I say if no image is loaded in the imageView the toolbar should not be shown?

Comment: @user3550084 do you understand now how to identify the source of the image? Once you understand that, then I suggest you read up on the fundamentals of iOS and objective-c so that you can do basic things such as hiding a toolbar. I'll give you a clue, it has something to do with the `hidden` property and injecting the code in the right if-else condition.

Comment: I think I get it. Could you have a look at the finish code (can be looked up in the original question)?

Comment: @user3550084 You are very close, whenever you want the toolbar hidden, you want to say `.hidden = YES` and whenever you want the toolbar to show, you do the opposite. I believe I have answered your original question. I will let you venture off on your own for a bit before you throw more code. I believe you are very close and just need to concentrate a bit more and do a bit more reading.

Comment: I edited the else code (form NO to YES) is now the code correct?

Comment: I dont know, you tell me? Why would an image not be shown? Maybe you want to do something like `if(imgView.image == NULL){ toolbar.hidden = YES;} else{ toolbar.hidden = NO; }`

Comment: The toolbar should be shown if an image is chosen from the photo gallery or taken by the camera. And if not the toolbar should be hidden. Yes, i get it.